# Config error for Scene Builder in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder, netbeans-8

I'm trying to set up Scene Builder in Netbeans.  I know I have to go into `window->options->java->javafx` and then enter the path to the Scene Builder home.  But I get this error message for everything I submit:

[image]

I'm on Windows 7 and am running JDK 1.8 update 40.
Netbeans is version 8.0.2.

I'm using this compile of Scene Builder: http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/

I know the directory after installing Scene Builder is `C:\Program Files (x86)\SceneBuilder` but if I use this path I still get the error.

Since most of the resources for Scene Builder are dated due to Oracle no longer providing binaries I can't find much on the subject of configuration for IDE's.  Does anyone have experience in setting this up in Netbeans and know what path I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

The scene builder application has to be located in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0

This buried patch is how I figured it out:

http://hg.netbeans.org/jet-main/rev/b3aa470c5d64

```
1.10  #WINDOWS
1.11  WIN_WKIP=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Oracle\\JavaFX Scene Builder $ver$;C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\JavaFX Scene Builder $ver$
```

Comment: I'll check once I get home and update accordingly, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but no it did not work.  I have the `SceneBuilder.exe` located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0` but when I specify the folder location in Netbeans I still get the same error message.  I apologize if I'm not looking in the right place, but I do not know how to find information at the link you provided.  I don't see any comment thread or solution section.

Comment: Added a snippet from the link that was the clue.  The location of it is hardcoded to that path.  It wasn't finding it for me until I ensured that that's where it was.  Hope you get there!

Answer (score 0):

- Download JavaFX Scene Builder from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-downloads.html (you have to sign in) 
  and install it.
- Open your installed NetBeans
- Click Tools > Options > Java >
  JavaFX >
- Scene Builder Home: browse to : `C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder` 1.1 or `C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0` based on your installation.
- Click OK.